# How to use STIntersect in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I want to to perform a `STInteract` using two tables and finding the intersections of the lines onto a given polygon. I have converted all the tables to have geometries for all. I am having a problem writing the query for this.

These are my two table

1. HWY_Database = contains the lines
2. POLY_Database = Polygon of interest

This is my script:

```
--visually checking if they intersect
SELECT GEOM FROM [dbo].[HWY_Database] where STFIPS = '04'
UNION ALL 
SELECT NEATCELL FROM [dbo].[POLY_Database]
```

So I dont know how to write this so this what I Initially wrote:

```
--intersect Neatcell and GEOM
SELECT GEOM FROM [dbo].[HWY_Database] where STFIPS = '04'
Where GEOM.STIntersects(NEATCELL FROM [dbo].[POLY_Database])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GEOM 
FROM [dbo].[HWY_Database] as hwy
join [dbo].[POLY_Database] as p
    on hwy.GEOM.STIntersects(p.NEATCELL) = 1
where STFIPS = '04'
```